# Prevent knockout from calling subscribe when the observable is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have two inputs that are binded to their own observable. Both have a subscribe function that starts an ajax call. There are some other fields that will be filled out from the ajax result. I want to be able to get data when the companyName is typed. I also want to get the companyName (and more) when the cardNumber is typed, but giving companyName a value will trigger its subscibe function which will start another ajax call. I want to prevent this from happening.

```
cardNumber = ko.observable();
companyName = ko.observable();

cardNumber.subscribe(function () {
        getDataFromCardNumber(cardNumber());
});
companyName.subscribe(function () {
        getDataFromCompanyName(companyName());
});

getDataFromCardNumber = function (cardNr) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: { number: cardNr },
        url: '/Home/GetCardInfo',
        success: function (data) {
           companyName(data.Company.CompanyName);
           //some other fields
        }
    });
};
//getDataFromCompanyName(name) contains another ajax call to fill out some other fields aswell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options:

- You could `dispose` the subscription before writing from the callback, and then re-attach it when the new value is set.

```js
const obsA = ko.observable("a");
const obsB = ko.observable("b");

const updateA = newVal => setTimeout(
  () => {
    subA.dispose();
    obsA("reset by B");
    subA = obsA.subscribe(updateB);
  }, 500);
  
const updateB = newVal => setTimeout(
  () => {
    subB.dispose();
    obsB("reset by A");
    subB = obsB.subscribe(updateA);
  }, 500);


let subA = obsA.subscribe(updateB);
let subB = obsB.subscribe(updateA);

  
ko.applyBindings({ obsA, obsB });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
A: <input data-bind="value: obsA" />
B: <input data-bind="value: obsB" />
```

- You can create separate UI observables that call updates in their `write` logic:

```js
const obsA = ko.observable("a");
const obsB = ko.observable("b");

const uiObsA = ko.computed({
  read: obsA,
  write: val => {
    obsA(val);
    updateB();
  }
});

const uiObsB = ko.computed({
  read: obsB,
  write: val => {
    obsB(val);
    updateA();
  }
});

const updateB = newVal => setTimeout(
  () => obsB("reset by A"), 500);
  
const updateA = newVal => setTimeout(
  () => obsA("reset by B"), 500);
  
ko.applyBindings({ obsA, obsB });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
A: <input data-bind="value: uiObsA" />
B: <input data-bind="value: uiObsB" />
```

Comment: The writeable computed functions is what I was looking for. This helped me solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You could always just check to see if a card number or company name exists already before you call the ajax request.

```
cardNumber.subscribe(function () {
    if (!companyName()){
       getDataFromCardNumber(cardNumber());
    }
});

companyName.subscribe(function () {
    if (!cardNumber()){
        getDataFromCompanyName(companyName());
    }
});
```